# Solving a large systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was wondering how one might solve a systems of equations like this:

$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4+\ldots = a_n$

$b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3+b_4x_4+\ldots = b_n$

$c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3+c_4x_4+\ldots = c_n$

$\vdots$

$z_1x_1+z_2x_2+z_3x_3+z_4x_4+\ldots = z_n$

---

Given values $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots a_n$ to $z_1, z_2, z_3, \ldots z_n$ are all known and $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer, how would I solve for $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots x_n$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Gaussian elimination or some iterative method for an approximate solution.

Comment: Usually large systems of linear equations are solved numerically, by various iterative procedures, as the previous comment pointed out

Comment: Using Gaussian elimination worked great for me. Thanks for the help!